# How to Get the size of the filtered array in Mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
db.FlaggedData.aggregate([
{
    "$match": {
        "_id": "d86d6b48-e949-4daa-8364-9ef008416ae8"
    }
},
{
    "$project": {
        "users": {
            "$slice": [
                {
                    "$filter": {
                        "input": "$users",
                        "as": "users",
                        "cond": {
                            "$and": [
                                { SOME FILTERS
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    } 
                },
                0,
                100
            ]
        },
        "count": {"$size": "$users"}
    }
    
}
```

])

How do I get the size of the filtered results?

as what I'm doing now I'm getting the size of the Array, not the size of the filtered result.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to put entire `$slice` into count.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": "d86d6b48-e949-4daa-8364-9ef008416ae8"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "users": {
        "$slice": [
          {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$users",
              "as": "user",
              "cond": {
                "$and": [
                  {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$user.name",
                      "123"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          0,
          100
        ]
      },
      "count": {
        "$size": {
          "$slice": [
            {
              "$filter": {
                "input": "$users",
                "as": "user",
                "cond": {
                  "$and": [
                    {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$user.name",
                        "123"
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            0,
            100
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-TCkejWpq6I)

**OR**

- Use two `project`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": "d86d6b48-e949-4daa-8364-9ef008416ae8"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "users": {
        "$slice": [
          {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$users",
              "as": "user",
              "cond": {
                "$and": [
                  {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$user.name",
                      "123"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          0,
          100
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      users: {
        "$size": "$users"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xqfUw29bdE4)

Comment: Thank you so much.
The second approach seems more elegant to implement,
added another projection stage.

`{ "$project": {  "users": 1,  "count": {  "$size": "$users"   }   }  }`